# Getting error: control reaches end of non-void function dont know why

Tags: c++, syntax

I keep receiving the following error and I have no idea whats wrong

```
cc1plus: warnings being treated as errors
scene.cpp: In member function ‘Image* Scene::getpicture(int) const’:
scene.cpp:179: error: control reaches end of non-void function
```

Here is the part of the code that the error is in:

```
Image* Scene::getpicture(int index) const {

    if(index<0 || index >maximum)
        cout << "invalid index" << endl;
    else {
        return images[index]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `images[]` an array of `image` or an array of `*image`?

Answer (score 7):

If the code does not enter the `else` statement, nothing gets returned. Therefore you need to insert a return either at the end or when you enter the if-statement.

Answer (score 3):

When the condition of the `if` statement is true, then the function doesn't return a value, because there is no `return` statement that's executed in that case.

You need to return a value (or throw an exception). For example:

```
Image* Scene::getpicture(int index) const {
    if (index < 0 || index > maximum) {
        cout << "invalid index" << endl;
        return NULL;  // Return NULL in case of an invalid index
    } else {
        return images[index];
    }
}
```